# How to deal with transactional logs in Fabric8?

Tags: docker, openshift, fabric8

Probably a quite newbie question:

If for example WildFly application server in running in 10 immutable pods, when one of the pods for any reason is killed and a new one is automatically spawned all transactional logs stored in that specific pod will be lost. Is there a standard way to deal with this problem?

Thanks!

Vas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way of dealing with things like this is to use a [Persistent Volume](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/) to mount any durable state you need in your application sever pod instance; so that whenever the pod is restarted on another node your persistent state is still available